# jQuery AJAX convert between encodings

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on a TinyMCE plugin that will be very simple. I will supply URL, plugin will download page HTML from that given URL and paste the page body into to TinyMCE editor. I have however came up with encoding problem. My page is using utf-8 encoding, but target page is using windows-1250 encoding. When I try to download URL content the result will look like shown below. If the target HTML page uses utf-8 everything is working fine.

My Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'get',
    contentType: 'text/html; charset=windows-1250',
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        result = data;
    }
});
```

Result contains text:

> Zbo�� mus� b�t fakturov�no v obdob� akce.
>   Akce je omezena na maxim�ln� 5ks kod� na resellera.

Is there a way how to convert HTML stored in result variable from windows-1250 to utf-8? (using Javascript preferably.. I can do this using C#, but that is not possible in this case)

Thanks for your help!

Headers:

Request:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:cs-CZ,cs;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:text/html; charset=windows-1250
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Response:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Content-Length:7365
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Wed, 06 Nov 2013 13:18:01 GMT
ETag:"5c9ff138d7dace1:0"
Last-Modified:Wed, 06 Nov 2013 10:01:54 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Comment: `contentType` is for the sent data, not for the received one. What header does the target page send (I don't think you can overwrite that with the `dataType` parameter)?

Comment: Did you try to use something like this: 
     contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
in your ajax function?

Comment: Hey, thx for your help. Bergi - you are probably right. Sahin Yanlik - yes I have tried that, but with same result :(

Comment: charlietfl is right. Remove that `contentType: 'text/html; charset=windows-1250',` parameter from the `ajax` call (you're not sending any data), and send the used `charset` in the response (from your ASP.NET server).

Comment: @Bergi the problem is that I do not have access to the server, so I can not change charset.